# Android BottomNavigationView - set line as itemBackground

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to figure out a clean and elegant way of how to have a simple line at the top of each **selected** item on `BottomNavigationView`.

What I have now:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/bottom_nav_selector"
            app:itemRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@color/green"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

Selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_nav_selected_indicator" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_nav_unselected_indicator" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Selected drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- This is the green line -->
    <item
        android:right="25dp"
        android:left="25dp">
        <shape>

            <stroke
                android:width="6dp"
                android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Unselected drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- This is the green line -->
    <item
        android:right="25dp"
        android:left="25dp">
        <shape>

            <stroke
                android:width="4dp"
                android:color="#FFF" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

What I'd like to achieve - just have the **line at the top and not at the bottom** as it is shown in picture:

[image]

My solution works, but it feels hacky. Isn't there some cleaner way of achieving what I want?